# kotlin native cinterop add linkerOpts of source code

Tags: kotlin-native, cinterop

I add one header file and its source to my xcode project.

For example , AddToo.h

```
@interface AddTool : NSObject


-(NSString*) test:(NSString*) string;

@end
```

And the follow is source code

```
@implementation AddTool

-(NSString*) test:(NSString*) string {

    return string;
}

@end
```

**test.def**

```
language=Objective-C
headers=AddTool.h
package=com.tomliu
```

when I run the xcode project,

the error occurs

*Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AddTool", referenced from:*

So should I build AddTool as static library first and add it to linkerOpts in .def file ?

Any other way to resolve this issue?

My kotlin version is 1.3.72

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This answer copies my answer on this question's duplicate located in the YouTrack-based Kotlin issue tracker(see [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39562)). 
As far as I know, one cannot make things work this way. Even though you can use a `cinterop` tool with this `.def` file as input, it will emit only bindings for a C library or Objective-C library/framework. Those bindings are like headers, they do not contain actual code, they should point onto an object file or a shared library. So yes, compiling a static library should help here.